# Wordpress Object Values

Tags: php, wordpress, object, post

I am using Custom Post Types with Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress 3.7.1. Within one of my CPTs I am referencing another Custom Field as a Post Object. When retrieving the Post Object through WP_Query I am able to return the Post Object ID but need to get the text value of the object (the title of the Custom Post Type).

```
<?php
$related_query = new WP_Query( $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'videos',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'video_category'    => $on_category,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'post__not_in'  => array($this_post),
    'posts_per_page'    => 2
));

if ($related_query->have_posts()): while ($related_query->have_posts()) : $related_query->the_post(); ?> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <p class="related_title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $post->video_presenter; //returns object id ?> | <?php echo $post->video_date; ?></p>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does var_dump($post) give you?

Comment: I used print_r($the_post); and was able to get a list of all the associative properties and values of the post. var_dump($post) gave me a list of properties but with the values listed out as string(length).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that I was looking for.

```
<?php 
    $post_id = $post->video_presenter;
    $the_post = get_post($post_id);
    print_r($the_post);
    $title = $the_post->post_title;
?>
```